# What is the most effective way to pick in ranked teams?

Tags: league-of-legends

When picking champions in ranked teams it is always a good idea to trick the other team. For example: Picking a champion that can go mid, jungle or top will make it harder for the other team to counter pick.

But it's hard to do that with every champion. So which roles are the most important to surprise the enemy team with?

Is it better to pick a surprise jungler/AD carry or AP carry/Solo top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of strategy goes into the picks and bans phase of League of Legends?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/what-kind-of-strategy-goes-into-the-picks-and-bans-phase-of-league-of-legends)

Answer (score 1):

Usualy the best picks is Support and AD carry as first 2 picks, then jungler, then mid and then top. Top is usualy the place where the most counterpicking is so try make pick top as lastpick. Unless you can get one of those perma-banned champs like shen/morg/shaco since they all got very safe lane phases.

Answer (score 0):

Generally support is a safe pick as you can't really counter a support. Also picks like Udyr, Shyvana and Lee Sin are safe too as they can go top or jungle. I don't really know any AD carries that excel in the jungle so i wouldnt do that. Also picks like kennen and vlad can go both top or mid so they too are safer picks.